# Files with the extension .out

Tags: file-extensions

I use Git as the version control manager for my TeX projects. I use the `.gitignore` file to indicate to Git which files not to track. I have annotated the entries of my `.gitignore` file so as to indicate next to each exclusion why it is to be ignored, and why files of this type are generated in the first place. One of the file types I'd like to ignore is files ending with `.out`. However, I'm not sure what these files are for, and what component generates them. I'm not even sure they are generated by the TeX system; they may be generated by Emacs, which is my source code editor, or by Libre Office. Are files with the extension `.out` genereted by some TeX component or package (e.g. PGF/TikZ)? If so, what is their purpose?

Comment: Have you tried to peek into them? Are they binary? Text?

Comment: @Rmano I didn't peek into it when I had the opportunity, and now I no longer have an example of such a file in my folder.

Comment: They're generated by [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: I'll check when Ill arrive at office. .out is probably quite common around there (I think some Spice version also use them).

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I use hyperref, so it may well be it. Is there a general method I can use in the future to check the provenance of other TeX-related file types by their suffix?

Comment: @EvanAad: Yes; check the linked duplicates. [This file](https://github.com/wspr/latex-auxfiles/blob/master/auxfiles.tex) has not been updated in a while, and may not be exhaustive.